# String to Array Conversion

Tags: php

Hello how can i convert string to array but it should be in **nested** format. like i show in the example.

first i tried to explode "/" then i try static variable in foreach loop.. but no luck.

i'm beginner & still confused how to do this..

FROM

```
$str = 'first/second/third';
```

To

```
array(
    'first' => array(
        'second' => array(
            'third' => array(

            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: @PravinS tried but it did not came as i expected.. i mean nested format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply cleverness :p

```
$keys = explode("/",$str);
$result = array();
$ref = &$result;
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $ref[$key] = array();
    $ref = &$ref[$key];
}
unset($ref); // delete the reference
```

Comment: And thank you for actually using the code I gave you :p So many people take my working code, which I've tested, and come back saying it doesn't work, only to reveal that they had tried to type it themselves rather than copy-pasting and, of course, missed the main point of the answer XD In this case, a hapless user might have entirely missed the `&` symbols, which of course breaks the entire code, resulting in an empty result array.